# how to sort an array by string and number and date property using reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hi I made a project and sort in three ways:date,title,number but all of them are not working even through there is no any bug notification.So I do not know how to entry the bugging process.Please help me,thanks.

```
import ColorCards from "./ColorCards";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import data from "./initialState.json";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";

export default function CardsafterEvents({ title, color }) {
  const [colors, setColors] = useState(data.colors);
  const onRemove = (id) => {
    const newcolors = colors.filter((color) => color.id !== id);

    setColors(newcolors);
  };
  const AddColor = (title, color, timestamp) => {
    const newcolors = [
      ...colors,
      {
        id: uuidv4(),
        title: title,
        color: color,
        timestamp: timestamp
      }
    ];
    setColors(newcolors);
  };
  const SortbyDate = () => {
    const newcolors = colors.sort(
      (a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)
    );
    setColors(newcolors);
  };
  const SortbyTitle = () => {
    const newcolors = colors.sort((a, b) =>
      a.title > b.title ? 1 : b.title > a.title ? -1 : 0
    );
    setColors(newcolors);
  };
  const SortbyRating = () => {
    const newcolors = colors.sort((a, b) => a.rating - b.rating);
    setColors(newcolors);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <ColorCards
        dataColors={colors}
        handleDelete={onRemove}
        HandleColor={AddColor}
        onDate={SortbyDate}
        onTitle={SortbyTitle}
        onRating={SortbyRating}
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

Full project link:https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-62eh0?file=/CardsafterEvents.js:0-1330

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code would have worked if not for the fact that your Sort functions are mutating the state variable. Yes, `sort` will mutate the original array and thus this:

```
const newcolors = colors.sort((a, b) =>
      a.title > b.title ? 1 : b.title > a.title ? -1 : 0
    );
```

actually alters your `colors` state variable. Of course, that's a no no in React. I will show you how to make your `SortbyTitle` function work and you can do the same for the other Sort functions as well. You need to create a copy of the sate variable and only then use `sort` on it. Try this:

```
  const SortbyTitle = () => {
    const copy_of_ar = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(colors));
    copy_of_ar.sort((a, b) =>
      a.title > b.title ? 1 : b.title > a.title ? -1 : 0
    );

    setColors(copy_of_ar);
  };
```

And here is a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-dudix?file=/CardsafterEvents.js) for you with a working Title sorter.

Comment: thanks@codemonkey,it work with the initial state,but after`add color`,it not work with all states including `added color`,I made following your instruction as the following link:https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-evsk5?file=/CardsafterEvents.js

Comment: @juexu It works fine for me. Are you adding colors that start with a lowercase latter? like "red"? If so colors that start with upper case letters like "Tomato" will always be sorted first. That's just how sorting works. Add a new color like "Green" and sort by title, it will work.

Comment: ,I use uppercase but `rating`and`date` sort is not working,`title`sort is working.

Comment: @juexu *I will show you how to make your SortbyTitle function work and you can do the same for the other Sort functions as well*. So yeah, the idea was to just show you how to fix one function assuming you will do the same for the others.

Answer (score 0):

The functions don't have access to your `colors` and `setColors` in the context that they are called. You need to send them to they child with those as arguments eg:

```
const SortbyDate = (colors, setColors) => {
    const newcolors = colors.sort(
      (a, b) => new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date)
    );
    setColors(newcolors);
  };
```

and then:

```
<ColorCards
...
  onDate={() => SortbyDate(colors, setColors)}
...
/>
```

OR send down the `colors` and `setColors` as their own props and then use them when you call the function eg:

```
<ColorCards
...
  colors={colors}
  setColors={setColors}
  onDate={SortbyDate}
...
/>
```

and in the child component:

```
props.onDate(props.colors, props.setColors)
```

Comment: appreciate quick response and I can not follow your suggestion.thanks@Sean